# Whatsapp (Android) makes some pictures blank and appear black while sending on LG G3

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, lg-g3

Steps:

1. Capture some pictures, say 10 pictures 
   -- I am able to see all images in the Gallery
2. Attach all of them in whatsapp 
   -- I am able to see all images in the preview
3. Send
   -- Some pictures turn black (actually they are empty; I checked the size)
4. To the receiver also, same observation, that is some are black and some are alright.

What is the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: Does it happen also if someone else will take the same steps to send you a bunch of pictures?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the app? After reinstalling it you may be able to have the backup restore the images.

Comment: @ arieljannai : No, that does not happen while receiving pictures

Comment: @ Devin Ersoy: Yes, I tried reinstalling but it didn't work